# How to Substract two numbers with positive result without using if else and any built-in methods to check which number is greater in python

Tags: python, math

Is there is any way to substract two numbers without using if else and return always positive right result.
Note: we are considering that we have to substract smaller one from larger one always. But user can enter the value in any sequence so we have to check that which num is greater. But we are restricted to use any builtin method and if else for that.
ex :  input value = 5-10 = -5
but we have to do 10 - 5 without using if else and built- in methods to find which number is greater to substract larger from smaller.

Comment: Just `abs(a-b)` is okay......

Comment: Nope. We can't use any builtin methods.

Comment: No, to subtract great from lesser will always yield a negative answer. So your question is a paradox.

Comment: I think you haven't checked the below method given by @Tukay

Comment: I suspect you understand neither the spelling nor the meaning of subtract. Can you show an example of subtracting a greater quantity from a lesser and yielding a positive result? 10-5 is subtracting 5 (lesser) from 10 (greater).

Comment: I apologise for my mistake. I have edited my question

Comment: It isn't my intent to be rude, but rather to help. It isn't clear to me what you are after. I am glad you found an answer that satisfies, but this question still isn't suitable. Subtracting 2 numbers doesn't always have a positive result. @Tuqay's answer does illustrate an interesting way to find the absolute value of the difference between 2 positive integers or of the absolute values of two integers, but if either argument is negative things aren't so clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225512/discussion-between-theherk-and-codelover).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this:

```
a = 10
b = 5

squared = -(a-b)*(b-a)
```

We know that either `a-b` or `b-a` is negative. So `-(a-b)*(b-a)` is always positive. Then we can find what you want with power operator:

```
output = squared ** 0.5
```

If ** (power) isn't applicable in your case, let me know

Comment: Why we have used 0.5 in power? What's the reason?

Comment: @CodeLover,  0.5 in power equals to square root

Answer (score -2):

This way.

```
r = lambda a, b: (a-b, b-a)[a < b]
```